# 3 meter high stand + 3 meters long arm

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod

I need to place a camera above the floor, for shooting a scene. I'd like to have a setup that allows me to go 3m tall + 3m toward the center of the scene.
What sort of equipment should I get (preferibly low to medium price range)? 
I'm planning to use a compact camera, its weight below 300 grams, and the camera doesn't need to move.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd be unlikely to get a stand that can stand itself up like that. How about using a pair of ladders or the like, one on either side of the scene, supporting a board or plank of wood or something, that crosses over the top of the scene? Should be relatively cheap to do as one possible solution

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I'm looking for a more sturdy/compact setup. I'm planning to move it and set it up more times in different places. I forgot to mention that I'll use a compact camera, so the stand has to bear little weight. I've edited the question adding that information.

Comment: If you have some DIY skill you can just buy some tubes and a counterweight and scaffold it all together.

Comment: It may actually be cheaper to rent a cherry picker if it's for occasional use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device you need is called a crane.  They are, however, not particularly cheap.  They are also not particularly compact generally as they require a counterweight system and have to be very strong to deal with even a light weight with that much of a lever arm.

Here is B&H's selection of [cranes](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Cranes-Jibs/ci/3917/N/4028759234).

Comment: Thanks a lot AJ. Yeah, they are way out of my budget, but I think also way over my needs. I don't need to be moving the camera, I need to shoot just a static scene. I'll go edit that :)

Comment: @cagnarrogna - doesn't matter if you need them to move, they are the only option that does what you are talking about (unless you go with the two towers and a truss between them, but making those highly portable is still going to probably cost more than the crane and be less portable.  A static crane requires all the same things a moving one does and most cranes can be locked in place.

Comment: isn't there any possibility a stand + some kind of clamp + an arm will work for that? That's what I had in mind, but didn't know what to choose for having the setup stable.

Comment: @cagnarrogna - that's what a crane is.  You have to have a counter-weight on the boom in order to avoid the whole thing falling over.  You also need to be able to adjust the position and lock it in place.  That's all a crane is, particularly the cheap ones.  Nicer ones have smoother motion, but the cheap ones are pretty basic.

Comment: @cagnarrogna: a stand and arm with a sandbag on the stand will work... when the arm and stand are perhaps less than 1.5m. The weight of the size you want is basically what necessitates a crane.

Comment: I agree with @Dan, the laws of physics dictate that you need a counterbalance; for 3m high then 3m reach, that requires a heavy counterbalance. You can't defy gravity unfortunately

Comment: ....unless the vertical pole has a spike that you can stick into the ground. Note that this doesn't mean you don't need a counterbalance, it means that you are using the earth around the base of the pole as the counterbalance weight